# I just entered the USA without passport control at Atlanta airport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, pre-clearance, nexus

I'm a Canadian NEXUS holder, and I landed at Atlanta airport earlier this morning on a Delta flight. Exiting from the plane, the security (or an airport worker) guided me to an exit through the hall.  I ended up at the airport train platform. I got in the train and got off at the international baggage claim area, and then exited the airport without any problem. I was not aware that this is strange until my friend told me that it's abnormal and might get me into a big trouble. Should I call the airport or TSA, or does this happen normally (or at least from time to time?)

I flew from Toronto Pearson Airport and scanned my passport and answered several questions on the NEXUS kiosk (including the address I will be staying); I guess it was pre-clearing. But how did the security know if I already pre-cleared at Toronto airport and opened up the door to separate hallway?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't pre-clear at your Canadian airport of departure?

Comment: I flew from pearson airport and scanned my passport and answered several questions on nexus kiosk(including the address i will be staying), I guess it was preclearing..

Comment: but how the hell did the security know if i already precleared at toronto airport and openned up the door to separate hallway ?

Comment: If I were you I'd' check my records at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov, though I don't know what you would normally find as a nexus member.

Comment: Yeah the "nexus kiosk" was your preclearance. Because you have trusted traveler cards, it was very minimal, but that was the inspection. CBP can decide to re-inspect arriving precleared flights, but there is no reason to do so absent special circumstances so that's not normal procedures. Everyone who flies out of Toronto goes through preclearance (if they're flying to the US I mean) so the whole plane was precleared, unless they had nexus cards they would have gone in line with everyone else.

Comment: @theonlygusti When the plane landed, they knew the plane came from Toronto, and the *entire flight* had gone through preclearance, because that's their policy and normal procedure.  They were also confident in Toronto's airplane access controls and, lacking any evidence to the contrary, assumed that nobody joined the flight mid-air en route as that is physically quite difficult.

Comment: @WBT yeah i know, my comment was clearly mocking the OP which is probably why it no longer exists

Comment: @WBT But not totally outside the realm of possibility...[Man on runway in underwear - Atlanta](https://youtu.be/8U6SCv-SVI0)

Comment: @CGCampbell Correct; odd incidents happen.  If there is an exceptional case that authorities think warrants re-screening, they will re-screen.  However, if there were no incident at the airport of departure and the precleared plane is arriving sealed, with any incident at the destination airport relatively contained elsewhere, they might still not re-screen. Border security processes are always tradeoffs based on evaluation of risk and relative cost, recognizing that no system is 100.000...% perfect.

Answer (score 120):

You went through [US CBP Preclearance](https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance) in Toronto before boarding your flight. This is US immigration and customs, with US immigration officers stationed on Canadian soil, and unless something unusual occurs, that means your flight arrives in the US in the same way as a US-to-US domestic flight, with no need for any further procedures to enter the country.

Since you're a NEXUS holder, your trip through immigration was short and simplified, as the US considers you a trusted traveler with no need to see an officer unless you have something to declare or are selected for further scrutiny.

As for your second question:

> but how the hell did the security know if i already precleared at toronto airport and openned up the door to separate hallway ?

Everyone on your flight went through preclearance, because that was part of the process before you could get to your boarding gate in Toronto. The airline's staff in Atlanta knew you were on a preclearance flight and opened the appropriate doors to direct you into the airport concourse instead of the secure corridors to the immigration hall. If you had arrived in the US on a non-preclearance flight (say, a flight from London), they instead would have ensured that your only path was to the immigration hall, and you would not be able to leave the airport until you went through immigration and customs. If the airline staff does somehow screw that up, there could be substantial fines for the airline and a great deal of trouble and inconvenience for everyone (as occurred during [this incident in Chicago](https://wgntv.com/2019/05/30/international-passengers-bypass-customs-during-apparent-security-breach-at-ohare/)).

Comment: I've also experenced the same from flying Dublin to Newark. I'm an Irish Citizen.

Comment: @DeanMeehan Yes, it's worth pointing out that while most of the preclearance locations are in Canada and the Caribbean, there are also a few locations elsewhere (Ireland and the UAE). https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance

Comment: UAE?!? I would love to know how that came about. I would have expected, at the very least, another five-eyes country before any middle eastern country.

Comment: @dotancohen I'd guess something about screening people before allowing them to get onto a plane? After all, they've proven in the past they don't need to land in the US to be a problem.

Comment: @djsmiley2k: That applies to any passenger at any airport. For some reason, Canada, Ireland, and UAE have a special arrangement. Based on the known relations between the United States and other nations, I can understand Canada being exceptional and perhaps - with a stretch - Ireland. But UAE is a surprise, especially considering that e.g. Australia does not seem to have such an exception.

Comment: Ireland has the IRA, UAE is... well there's people of colour, and the US is the US. Either way it was just a throw away thought.

Comment: It has nothing to do with any special relationship. Those countries agreed to allow US CBP officers to act as law enforcement(as in they can arrest you) on their soil for the purpose of pre-screening flights to the US for the economic benefit of having easier flights to the US. Other countries did not want to give up sovereignty like that.

Comment: @dotancohen The US would love to have pre-clearance on every airport with flights to the USA. It's not a gesture from the US to other countries. It's a gesture from other countries to the USA. Most countries aren't willing to hand over that much power to the USA.

Comment: @Abigail in Canada's case, the preclearance agreement is actually reciprocal, but Canada hasn't seen fit to implement preclearance in US airports.  I haven't seen the agreements with the other countries, but I imagine they're also reciprocal.  This would only be for saving face, however, since these countries are so much smaller than Canada, and it would be even more inefficient for them to send officers to US airports than it is for Canada.

Comment: @Eugene the preclearance agreement allows US officers in Canada to "detain" people for violating of Canadian criminal law, but not to enforce US criminal law. Detainees must of course be transferred promptly to Canadian custody. US officers can only administer US customs and immigration law, and then only partially. If a "partial body search" is needed under US law, the search is to be conducted by Canadian officers (unless they cannot perform the search promptly). In other words, Canada doesn't give up as much as one might think, but there is a lot of negotiation behind these agreements.